# Too small a frame to occupy a panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Could you help me understand what is wrong with my arythmetics.
I need checks with a side of 30. Between the checks there is a line whose thickness is 1.

The frame cuts away the last column and the last row and a half of the last but one.

```
public class GlassView extends JFrame {
    private final int WIDTH = 309;
    private final int HEIGHT = 681;
    public GlassView() {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
    private final int WIDTH = 309;
    private final int HEIGHT = 681;

    public DrawPanel(){
        this.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
        for (int i = 31; i < WIDTH; i+=31){
            g2.drawLine(i, 0, i, HEIGHT);
        }

        for (int i = 31; i < HEIGHT; i+= 31){
            g2.drawLine(0, i, WIDTH, i);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the sequence I calculated in Excel (by adding 31):

```
31
62
93
124
155
186
217
248
279
310 // 10
341
372
403
434
465
496
527
558
589
620
651
682 // 22
```

Well, for me everything is logical: at 310 and 682 there is no line. But the frame is too small to hold such a checked panel. Could you help  me understand what I'm doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"JFrame" extends "Jframe", which extends "Window", by setting size of it you don't take in count the borders. Borders can vary, depending on the platform, so putting fixed change to "JFrame" is bad idea.

go this way

```
 public GlassView() {
     DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
     panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT)); //you need it for "pack()"
     this.add(panel);
     //this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
     this.pack();
     int h=this.getHeight();
     int w=this.getWidth();
     System.out.println(h);
     System.out.println(w);
     this.setVisible(true);
 }
```

and thus

```
 run:
 708
 317
```